# Complete print Machzor Vitry

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, rishonim, nusach-ashkenaz

I was looking through Seforim Center the other day and found a partial edition ([volumes 1&2 here](https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=3082&strReferer=search&PPGR=0) and and a third on the same site) of the Machzor Vitry. Is there a complete print (or digital) edition of this sefer with clear, crisp type available?

Comment: That's very strange since I own the while set and it's in 3 volumes, it's a beautiful set. I don't remember where I got it.

Comment: http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=604

Comment: @sam, I didn't realise that it was only three volumes

Comment: @sam As I saw now, this edition is great, but incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You should try purchasing from here. I always had a good experience. This is a 3 volume, new edition for about $60.00 US depending on shipping and exchange rate.

https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/mhzvr-vitri-g-krkim-sdvr-hdw.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97649/discussion-on-answer-by-yaacov-deane-complete-print-machzor-vitry).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to locate a complete copy of the edition in [sam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1418/sam)'s [comment](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=604) at the YU Seforim Sale.

Comment: Again, it's not the complete edition. This is the last page of it in the older (less precise) edition: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49459&st=&pgnum=66

Comment: @Kazibácsi, the edition sold at the Seforim Sale was complete and the listing in Sam's comment specifically mentions that all three kerachim are together

Comment: I was looking for this part, but I couldn't find it (do you have it @YaacovDeane ?): http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49459&st=&pgnum=68